# PHP foreach - undefined variable?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5.3's query builder, trying to add a where clause to find articles with a certain tag:

```
$tag_list = $request->tag_list; // tag_list is an array
if (isset($tag_list)) {
    foreach ($tag_list as $tag_id) {
        $query = $query->whereHas('tags', function ($query) {
            $query->where('id', $tag_id);
        });
    }
}
```

When I dump $tag_list I get...

```
24
```

But in the loop, I get an error:

```
Undefined variable: tag_id
```

What am I doing wrong? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `24` is not an array.

Comment: Are you sure that $tag_list is an array? If all you're getting back from a var_dump is `24` it looks like that var is a string or int.

Answer (score 7):

Because you are in function context. Pass tag_id variable via - **use** keyword

```
$tag_list = $request->tag_list; // tag_list is an array
if (isset($tag_list)) {
    foreach ($tag_list as $tag_id) {
        $query = $query->whereHas('tags', function ($query) use ($tag_id) {
            $query->where('id', $tag_id);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Ahhh I remember that now from a Laracasts tutorial... thanks @vuliad

Comment: For reference, also see http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php, "Example #3 Inheriting variables from the parent scope".